# tk.call( _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I want to set a theme to my tkinter window as well as config my tkinter window buttons, labels with options like bg.
Following is my approach,

Imports,

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
```

Code w/o setting the theme:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

rootlabel1 = Label(root, text="Total Income : ", bg = "red")  
rootlabel1.grid(row=1, column = 0)
rootlabel1.configure(anchor="center")

btn1 = Button(root, text = 'Add Income', pady = 20)
btn1.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

rootlabel = Label(root, text="Total Income : ")  
rootlabel.grid(row=4, column = 0)
rootlabel.configure(anchor="center")
root.mainloop()
```

Above was successful but did not had theme set.

Code after setting the theme:

```
root = ThemedTk(theme = "xpnative", themebg = True)
root.geometry('500x500')

rootlabel1 = ttk.Label(root, text="Total Income : ", bg = "red")  
rootlabel1.grid(row=1, column = 0)
rootlabel1.configure(anchor="center")

btn1 = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Add Income', pady = 20)
btn1.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

rootlabel = ttk.Label(root, text="Total Income : ")  
rootlabel.grid(row=4, column = 0)
rootlabel.configure(anchor="center")
root.mainloop()
```

I am getting the following error,

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/admin/Desktop/Stackoverflow/hskjf.py", line 11, in <module>
    rootlabel1 = ttk.Label(root, text="Total Income : ", bg = "red")
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 759, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::label", kw)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 557, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"
```

As soon as I add prefix **ttk.** to my buttons or labels
eg. - `btn1 = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Add Income', bg = "red")`
I am unable to use bg for these buttons/labels.

My Attempts,

```
1.   btn1 = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Add Income', bg = "red")

2.   rootlabel1 = ttk.Label(root, text="Total Income : ")  
       rootlabel1.grid(row=1, column = 0)
       rootlabel1.configure(anchor="center", bg = "red")
```

I am unable resolve the error, what I can do to fix it? so that I get both themes as well as options in my button/label.

(Previously, I wasnt able to use padx, pady but according to suggestion given in comment it worked well.)

Comment: You should put `pady` in the layout manager(like `.grid()`) instead of the config of widget.Try to use `.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=10)`.

Comment: It worked for padx, pady but I am unable to add color property eg, bg="red" to any of the lines It is giving me same type of error. *_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"*. Can you help me with this?

Comment: The Ttk widgets are not 100% drop-in replacements for the standard widgets.  They have *entirely different* methods for visual customization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the config of `grid` layout manager is [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).(Also,`padx` or `pady` is to set the padding.For sure it should be put in layout manager.)

---

Also,there are some differences between `tk` widget and `ttk` widget.In `tk` widget,you could use `bg` to set the background directly.But In `ttk` widget,you need to custom a `ttk.Style()`

In `tk` widget:

```
l1 = tkinter.Label(text="Test", bg="white")
```

But in `ttk` widget,you need to:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("BW.TLabel", background="white")

l1 = ttk.Label(text="Test", style="BW.TLabel")
```

---

Refer it in: [ttk-Styling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-styling)